# How can I write a recursive python function that splits a dictionary into an array of dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, recursion

I am looking to write a recursive function:

```
arguments: d, dictionary

result: list of dictionaries

def expand_dictionary(d):
    return []
```

The function recursively goes through a dictionary and flattens nested objects using an _, in addition it expands out nested lists into the array, and includes the parent label.

Think of creating a relational model from a document.

Here is an example input and output:

```
original_object = {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Alice",
    "last" : "Sample"
  },
  "cities" : [
    {
      "id" : 55,
      "name" : "New York"
    },
    {
      "id" : 60,
      "name" : "Chicago"
    }
  ],
  "teachers" : [
    {
      "id" : 2
      "name" : "Bob",
      "classes" : [
        {
          "id" : 13,
          "name" : "math"
        },
        {
          "id" : 16,
          "name" : "spanish"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

expected_output = [
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "name_first" : "Alice",
    "name_last" : "Sample"
  },
  {
    "_parent_object" : "cities",
    "id" : 55,
    "name" : "New York"  
  },
  {
    "_parent_object" : "cities",
    "id" : 60,
    "name" : "Chicago"  
  },
  {
    "parent_object" :"teachers",
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Bob"
  },
  {
    "parent_object" :"teachers_classes",
    "id" : 13,
    "name" : "math"
  },
  {
    "parent_object" :"teachers_classes",
    "id" : 16,
    "name" : "spanish"
  }
]
```

the code currently being used for flattening is:

```
def flatten_dictionary(d):
  def expand(key, value):
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        return [ (key + '_' + k, v) for k, v in flatten_dictionary(value).items() ]
      else:
        #If value is null or empty array don't include it
        if value is None or value == [] or value == '':
          return []
        return [ (key, value) ]

  items = [ item for k, v in d.items() for item in expand(k, v) ]

  return dict(items)
```

Comment: Is your 'original_obejct' a dictionary? so should there be 'comma' after '"id" : 1' at the first row?

Comment: correct, apologize for the syntax error.

Comment: Looks like you are destroying information: if you have more than one teacher, can you tell what classes each one teaches from the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

That will do

```
def expand_dictionary(d,name=None,l=None):
    obj = {}
    if l == None:
        l = [obj]
    else:
        l.append(obj)

    prefix = (name+'_'if name else '')
    if prefix: obj['_parent_object'] = name

    for i, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            map(lambda x:expand_dictionary(x,prefix+i,l),v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            obj.update(flatten_dictionary({i: v}))
        else:
            obj[i] = v
    return l
```

Comment: Not getting the correct output. i posted my solution i have been working on below.

Comment: Unless you mean the sorting, Its output matches the desired one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After working through it a bit here is what I have come up with. Probably can be significantly optimized. Based on @paulo-scardine's comment I added the parent primary key to keep the relational model. Would love to hear optimization thoughts.

```
def expand_dictionary(original_object, object_name, objects=None):
  if objects is None:
    objects = []
  def flatten_dictionary(dictionary):

    def expand(key, value):
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        return [ (key + '_' + k, v) for k, v in flatten_dictionary(value).items() ]
      else:
        #If value is null or empty array don't include it
        if value is None or value == [] or value == '':
          return []
        return [ (key, value) ]

    items = [ item for k, v in dictionary.items() for item in expand(k, v) ]
    return dict(items)

  original_object_root = flatten_dictionary(original_object).copy()
  original_object_root['_meta_object_name'] = object_name

  for key,value in original_object_root.copy().items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
      flatten_dictionary(value, objects)
    if isinstance(value, list):
      original_object_root.pop(key)
      for nested_object in value:
        nested_object['_meta_parent_foreign_key'] = original_object_root['id']
        nested_object['_meta_object_name'] = object_name + "_" + key
        expand_dictionary(nested_object, object_name + "_" + key, objects)

  objects.append(original_object_root)

  return objects
```